# How do you sort the values of arrays by grade (e.g. 85-100 is an A 70-84 is a B etc.)

Tags: java, arrays

I'm working on a program that stores values in an ArrayList and need to sort them by a corresponding grade like R, 1, 2, 3 and 4. How do I take the values in the array and sort them in that way?

I've tried basically nothing as I am very stumped.

```
public class MarksProgramUI extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    List<Integer> marksFinal = new ArrayList<>();
private void addButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          

    String marks = markInput.getText();
    int marksnum;
    marksnum = Integer.parseInt(marks);
    marksFinal.add(marksnum);
    Collections.sort(marksFinal);
    String output = " ";
    for ( int i=0;i<marksFinal.size();i++){
        output=output+marksFinal.get(i) + " ";
      }
    markOutput.setText(output + " " );
}                                     

private void analyseButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
resultOutput.setText("Class Average: " + calculateAverage(marksFinal) + "\n" + "Maximum Mark: " + calculateMaxValues(marksFinal) + "\n" + "Minimum Mark: " + calculateMinValues(marksFinal) + "\n");
}
```

Comment: If this question is related to sorting of ArrayList, you could turn it into a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) by removing the swing code, creating a sample code that we can just run and test our sorting.

Comment: Will do give me a second

Comment: Sorry having some issues at converting, I'm quite new to this. Is there any chance it could be done outside of that?

Comment: Why need sorting by grade?(maybe check for) For average sum all nums, divide over count(nums) [`marksFinal.size()`] and with a `case` return the right category. To place min, after natural order sort get  `marksfinal[0]` and with same `case` place in write category. For max the same but get last element `marksFinal.get(marksFinal.size()-1)`. It's possible to get same results based on sorting but need additional knowledge related to java8.

Comment: It's necessary for it to be sorted by grade for what I'm doing.

Comment: Obvious, that i can't have any idea of your usage of collecting by grade. From what you submitted to compute average, min, max and placing into a category there is no mandatory requirements based on collecting something grouped by grade. My advice is to keep it as simple as possible but here is up to you. In order for other to have a better understanding and give you an appropriate help it's useful to post also the usage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By "sorting" I assume you mean "grouping by". You can group marks as:-

```
List<Integer> marks = List.of(86, 74, 90, 40); //some dummy list of marks
Map<String, List<Integer>> map = marks.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(o -> {
            if (o < 50) return "F"; //assign grade 'F' to marks less than 50
            if (o < 65) return "1"; //assign grade '1' to marks from 50 to 64
            if (o < 75) return "2"; //65 to 74
            return "R"; //grade 'R' to 75 and above
        }));
System.out.println(map);
```

**Output**

```
{2=[74], R=[86, 90], F=[40]}
```

As you can see above, marks 86 and 90 are grouped together as grade 'R'.

You can change the above `if` conditions to suit your needs.

Comment: I'm getting an error on the line with the .collectors line. Is there something that should be added or am I missing something here?

Comment: @SpencerDiver what's the error? have you added import statements?

Comment: I have java.util.*. Should I add something else?

Comment: @SpencerDiver yes, you need to explicitly add `import java.util.stream.Collectors;` because `Collectors` in not directly inside `util`

Comment: Ok cool, only other problem is that it's saying it's missing the return statement. should I return map?

Comment: well, if you don't know how to add a return statement, how to add import statements, I suggest you to start reading a book on java instead of copy pasting this code in your project